# How to open view on top of existing views in iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

[image]
<sub>(source: [mashable.com](http://cdn.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/mashableipadapp2.png))</sub>

How do I go about opening a view in the way that you see in this example?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:]. This will allow you to do that exact effect.